# Symfony2 access_control, Match all routes containing some word

Tags: symfony

The following only matches a path that starts with `private`:

```php
access_control:
    #...
    - { path: ^/private, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    - { path: ^/private, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

How can I match all the routes that contain `/private/` (and do not necessarily start with `private`)? For example, something that will match `/message/private/blabla`..
the equivalent of `[path~="private"]` with [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

***Note:*** Does anyone know how we call the regex we are using here? Is this specific to yml or is this implemented by Symfony, I am confused. 
Is there a chance I missed this in the doc somewhere, I mean the description with the specific matching patterns like start with, end with, contains etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^/` this pattern says everything that starts (`^`) with slash (`/`) and so on.

I suppose that `/private` or something like `*/private` should work